# How to disable unicode option in Postman App

Tags: unicode, postman, postman-native-app

I am using my custom API endpoint on Postman app. My API endpoint returns response value along with unicode characters.

Response is displayed as unicode character instead of plain text value. How can I display the plain text for unicode characters in Postman App.

Plain text (\u1001) => Unicode character (ခ)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the response body to [Raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDbSN.png) should display plain text, though you'll lose indenting in the case of JSON objects.